# How can I make a letter equal an index number in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an inputted letter become a number.

For example, 'A' needs to equal 0, 'B' needs to equal 1, 'C' needs to equal 2, etc.

Comment: Look up 'enum's or 'enumeration' in Java.

Comment: Convert it to a `char` and get their number, then subtract the number of 'a' from all of them (assuming they are all lower case) and you're done.

Comment: It can be done in many ways. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

Just think along these lines:

If you subtract `'A'` from `'A'`, you get `0`. If you subtract `'A'` from `'B'`, you get `1`. If you subtract `'A'` from `'C'`, you get `2`. and so on.

Does it give you any pattern? You can create a formula out of this pattern.

**Try yourself. DISCOVER a formula!**

Since it seems to be homework, I will NOT give you the complete answer. :-)

Comment: +1 for _"I will NOT give you the complete answer"_ and simple answer

Comment: Please do not add the homework tag, it is deprecated. [tag:homework]

Comment: I'm pretty new at this. Not really a full-time programmer, just a high school student. But I hope you can help me make out what I'm doing here (it's supposed to be a game of tic-tac-toe): 

int player = 'X';

loc = input.nextLine();
marks[loc.charAt(1) - 1][loc.charAt(0) - 'A'] = player

Comment: @user1972720: I'm sure you can do this.Even a high school student can do it. Ask yourself this question : if someone gives you a `char`, say it is `x`, and it is also given that it is between `'A'` and `'Z'`, so what would you do to `x` to get the desired number? The only problem is that you have to make sure that `x` has to be between `'A'` and `'Z'`. Note that `'A'` is not same as `'a'`. They have different integral value (called ascii value)..

Comment: @Nawaz I'm guessing I would have to subtract 'A'?

Comment: @user1972720: Congrats. You finally discovered. Now how would you make sure that `x` falls in the range `['A', 'Z']`? And what would you do if it falls in `['a', 'b']` instead? What if it falls in neither of these range? Well that is probably an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    char input = 'e';

     int indexVal = letters.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(input));
```

Comment: Nice solution.... But it wont work if user passes myChar=e... Lower char...

Comment: @Jayamohan changed to handle case

Answer (score 0):

You can cast you `char` to an `int`, and substract by the value of `(int) 'A'`.
Like this :

```
char z = 'Z'
int number = (int) z - (int) 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

All chars have an int value, their ASCII value. You can cast a char to an int to get that value (and an int to a char to reverse it).

Extending on my comment, you could do this.

```
int aAsciiValue = (int)'a';
char input = however you get your input;
int result = (int)input - aAsciiValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). In it in advance to prepare "associations" between the character - its index

Answer (score 0):

```
public int letterToNumber(String letter) {
int letterNumber = letter.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[0] - 'a' + 1;
if (letterNumber < 1 || letterNumber > 26) {
    return 0;// Not a letter from a-z
}
return letterNumber;
}
```